# Using Serilog in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, serilog

Today at work I was asked to add some basic logging functionality in my existing ASP.NET MVC (not Core) project. I was told to use Serilog for this.

However, I failed to find any reasonable example of using Serilog in MVC, all links simply refer to Core. I tried to do everything myself. After installing all necessary packages (Serilog, Serilog.Sinks.File), I created a "Logs" folder and tried this:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.File("~/Logs/log.txt")
  .CreateLogger();

log.Information("Hello from Serilog!");
```

I expected to see a new file in the folder but there wasn't any. I also tried using a simpler path "log.txt" and creating a file in this folder preemptively but it didn't help.

Is it possible that Serilog is not supported for MVC at all? If it is, what is a simple way to log something into a text file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt Serilog understands the `~/` syntax in your path to your log file. `~/` refers to the virtual root of your site, but Serilog doesn't know anything about virtual roots or websites. It's just a logging framework and expects a normal path. So if you want to log to a file called log.txt in the Logs directory of your site, then you need to convert it to a proper path that Serilog can understand.

The [System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath) method can translate virtual root relative paths. So `~/Logs/log.txt` can become something like `C:\path-to-your-site\Logs\log.txt`.

Change to this:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Logs/log.txt"))
    .CreateLogger();

log.Information("Hello from Serilog!");    

//note that importing the namespace will make it so you don't have to fully qualify the name.
```

Then Serilog should log to the location you're expecting, if the directory exists and it has write privileges there.

File logging from a web application is going to get very messy. Unless your site gets hardly any usage, the logs are going to become unmanageable and useless. I suggest you look at the other Serilog sinks, and find one that logs to a logging service such as [Seq](https://getseq.net/) (from the makers of Serilog) or [Stackify Retrace](https://stackify.com/retrace/).